# Recursive Grammar in Pyparsing

Tags: python, recursion, grammar, pyparsing

I have the following JSON-like recursive grammar:

```
aerof_bnf_spec = """
inputfile
    block
    block inputfile
block
    under key { values }
values
    key = value;
    key = value; values
    block
    block values
key
    string
value
    string
    real
    int
"""

LBRACK, RBRACK, LBRACE, RBRACE, EQUAL, SEMICOLON = map(Suppress, "[]{}=;")
TAG = Suppress("under")
caps = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
lowers = caps.lower()
digits = "0123456789"

# define value
aerofNumber = pyparsing_common.number()
aerofFilePath = dblQuotedString().setParseAction(removeQuotes)
aerofString = Word(caps + lowers + digits)
aerofValue = (aerofNumber | aerofFilePath | aerofString)

# define key
aerofKey = Word(caps + lowers + digits)

# define key = value;
aerofPair = Group(aerofKey + EQUAL + aerofValue + SEMICOLON)

#define values and block recursively
aerofBlock = Forward()
aerofValues = Forward()
aerofBlock << Group(TAG + aerofKey + LBRACE + aerofValues + RBRACE) 
aerofValues << Dict((aerofPair | aerofBlock) + ZeroOrMore(aerofValues) )

# define inputfile
aerofInputFile = Dict(OneOrMore(aerofBlock))

# remove comment
aerofComment = cppStyleComment
aerofInputFile.ignore(aerofComment)
```

Once I change from

```
aerofValues << Dict((aerofPair | aerofBlock | (aerofPair + aerofValues)|(aerofBlock + aerofValues)) )
```

to

```
aerofValues << Dict((aerofPair | aerofBlock) + ZeroOrMore(aerofValues) )
```

the code works fine. My question is:

1. are they look equivalent?
2. If so, why does the first form not working in pyparsing?
3. Does pyparsing support all BNF grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aerofValues << Dict((aerofPair | aerofBlock | 
                    (aerofPair + aerofValues) | (aerofBlock + aerofValues)))
```

Since '|' resolves to MatchFirst expressions, the first listed expression that matches will be used for the match. If I defined a list of integers as:

```
integer_list <<= (integer | integer + integer_list)
```

and tried to parse "1 2 3 4", our integer_list would be satisfied by matching just the leading '1'.  Changing to:

```
integer_list <<= (integer + integer_list | integer)
```

Now gets us to first try the list of integers, and if multiple integers are not found, then see if just a single integer is present. But I would suggest implementing this with pyparsing as:

```
integer_list = OneOrMore(integer)
```

So your statements are very close to equivalent, and I think the first one will work if reordered to:

```
aerofValues << Dict(((aerofPair + aerofValues) | (aerofBlock + aerofValues) | aerofPair | aerofBlock) )
```

Or just:

```
aerofValues << Dict(OneOrMore(aerofPair | aeroOfBlock))
```

Pyparsing supports pretty much any BNF grammar, *as long as you do not contain left recursion*. Pyparsing will blow up on this expression:

```
integer_list <<= (integer_list + integer | integer)
```

By default, pyparsing does not do any lookahead on its own, but you can use `NotAny` (or operator `'~'`) and `FollowedBy` to specify lookaheads.

Also, pyparsing does not do backtracking, as you would see in a regular expression.